# Calculating Area Under The Precision Recall Curve with multiclass

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

I'm trying to calculate AUPR and when I was doing it on Datasets which were binary in terms of their classes, I used *average_precision_score* from *sklearn* and this has approximately solved my problem. However, when I tried to calculate average precision score on a multiclass dataset then its not supported according to *sklearn*.

Assuming I have to do this manually instead of using some *sklearn* metric, I'm trying to understand how can I calculate this and I would love some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate precision per class then take the average.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score

# For each class
precision = dict()
recall = dict()
average_precision = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    precision[i], recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(Y_test[:, i],
                                                        y_score[:, i])
    average_precision[i] = average_precision_score(Y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])

# A "micro-average": quantifying score on all classes jointly
precision["micro"], recall["micro"], _ = precision_recall_curve(Y_test.ravel(),
    y_score.ravel())
average_precision["micro"] = average_precision_score(Y_test, y_score,
                                                     average="micro")
print('Average precision score, micro-averaged over all classes: {0:0.2f}'
      .format(average_precision["micro"]))
```

Check these sklearn [Precision-Recall examaples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py).

[image: precision-recall curve]

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, there is a [multi-class implementation of the average precision](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/average_precision.html) in the `torchmetrics` module that also supports different averaging policies. Note that you would need to convert your numpy ndarrays with ground-truth labels and predictions into torch Tensors via `torch.from_numpy()` to use this implementation.